# Read file directly - simplified

Tags: c, strings, file, io

In order to read a whole file as a string using standard libraries you have to allocate memory, terminate the string, determine size of the file and size of each element.
This could happen with `fread` until I decided to automatize it using this:

```
char *readFile (FILE* fp, char *source)
{
    unsigned long long int size;
    unsigned long long int i = 0;
    int chr;

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);

    source = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(char));

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // rewind

    while(chr != EOF)
        source[i++] = (chr = fgetc(fp));

    source[size] = '\0';    // Terminate string

    return(source);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You let the user pass in a `char*` but you don't use it. you might as well remove it and declare it as a local variable.

```
char *readFile (FILE* fp)
{
    char* source;
```

Some `FILE*` won't let you seek to the end (stdin and socket streams for example). You should check the return value of `fseek` and fall back to the classic `fread` then `realloc`, rinse and repeat method on error.

A single `fread` is more efficient than the repeated `fgetc`; so you can replace the while with:

```
int readBytes = fread(source, size, 1, fp);

string[readBytes] = '\0';
```

Comment: How come I don't use it? The string will be copied to the `char*` destination the user specified.

Comment: The first thing you do with source is assign a freshly `calloc`ated chunk of memory to it. This overwrites the buffer the caller passed in and means that in all cases `buffer!=readFile(fp, buffer);`

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @Genis For all intents and purposes you ignore the value the caller passed in source.